# Counting journal reviews (when reviewing revisions)

Tags: peer-review

We've [discussed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29079/how-many-papers-should-i-be-reviewing-as-a-referee/29080#29080) how many papers we should review, but how do we count reviews? Sometimes I review 2-3 versions of a manuscript before it is finally accepted/rejected. Should I count each version that I review? Or should I just count each accept/reject decision?

Comment: I never bothered counting the number of reviews for my CV, but stated the years since when I was doing them. I do list some reviewer gratifications I get for doing so many reviews, but do not bother with exact numbers.

Comment: @OlegLobachev That's fair, and I actually am not as interested as counting them for my CV as I am in considering how many I should do in a year. Of course, I won't follow a set rule, but for the sake of understanding [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/29079/how-many-papers-should-i-be-reviewing-as-a-referee/29080#29080) popular thread

Comment: Oh, I see. For the sake of scaling I would egoistically count each major revision as a new review, as you'd need to read and review it again.

Comment: You can list the journals, e.g., X and Y, that you have reviewed for, along with the years reviews have been written, e.g., X'18, X'17, Y'17. In this case, it isn't known how many reviews you have written, nor how many articles you have reviewed.

Comment: @user2768 That's reasonable I suppose for the CV. Would you have any suggestions for the counting?

Comment: @Greenparker I had (mistakenly, it seems) assumed you were preparing your CV. Can you elaborate on why you want to count?

Comment: @user2768 The link in my question has a discussion for "how many reviews should one be doing", and the answers describe what number is reasonable. So I would like to know how one generally counts these.

Comment: Like @OlegLobachev I'd maximise my count.

Comment: @Greenparker I've tried to simplify your question. Please edit further if necessary.